# Join and pivot out results based on type column into different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a situation here and I need to fix this. I have two major tables
Personnel and ActualAdvanceDetails,
In ActualAdvanceDetails there are two types 0 and 1 which means 0 is Actual and 1 is Advance.

This is the stored data of my Actual Advance Table

```
EmployeeId Type RefNo Id
623        0    7     1
623        1    7     2
623        0    8     3
623        1    8     4
623        1  9    5
```

so here is the result of my query

```
IdEMPLOYEE NAMEPOSITIONId  RefNo Id RefNo
623 Aguil , Noli Barona UNDERCARRIAGE   Welder / Fabricator 1   7      2    7
623 Aguil , Noli Barona UNDERCARRIAGE   Welder / Fabricator 1   7      4    8
623 Aguil , Noli Barona UNDERCARRIAGE   Welder / Fabricator 1   7    5  9
623 Aguil , Noli Barona UNDERCARRIAGE   Welder / Fabricator 3   8      2    7
623 Aguil , Noli Barona UNDERCARRIAGE   Welder / Fabricator 3   8      4    8
623 Aguil , Noli Barona UNDERCARRIAGE   Welder / Fabricator 3   8      5    9
```

it should be

```
Id  EMPLOYEE NAME                       POSITION            Id  RefNo Id RefNo
623 Aguil , Noli Barona UNDERCARRIAGE   Welder / Fabricator 1   7      2    7
623 Aguil , Noli Barona UNDERCARRIAGE   Welder / Fabricator 3   8      4    8
623 Aguil , Noli Barona UNDERCARRIAGE   Welder / Fabricator            5    9
```

Here is my query

```
SELECT
    Per.[EmployeeId]
    ,CONCAT(GI.LastName, ' ', GI.NameExtension,', ', GI.FirstName,' ', GI.MiddleName) AS EmployeeName
    ,S.GroupDescription As Section
    ,Pos.PositionName As Position
    ,AC.Id
    ,AC.ReferenceNo
    ,AD.Id
    ,AD.ReferenceNo
FROM [FGCIJOROSystemDB].[dbo].[Personnels] AS Per
LEFT JOIN Sections As S ON S.Id = Per.SectionId
LEFT JOIN FGCIHRDMasterlistSystemDB.dbo.EmployeesInformations AS EI ON EI.Id = Per.EmployeeId
LEFT JOIN FGCIHRDMasterlistSystemDB.dbo.GeneralInformations AS GI ON GI.Id = EI.GeneralInformationsId
LEFT JOIN FGCIHRDMasterlistSystemDB.dbo.Positions As Pos ON Pos.Id = EI.PositionsId
LEFT JOIN ActualAdvanceDetails AS AC ON AC.EmployeeId = Per.EmployeeId AND AC.Type = 0
LEFT JOIN ActualAdvanceDetails AS AD ON AD.EmployeeId = Per.EmployeeId AND AD.Type = 1
WHERE S.IsChecklistGroup = 1
ORDER BY S.GroupDescription, GI.LastName
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After understanding your query in detail, I would like to propose conditional aggregation. You may also try pivot.

```
SELECT 
    EmployeeId
    ,EmployeeName
    ,Section
    ,Position
    ,MAX(Case when Type=0 then id end)
    ,ReferenceNo
    ,MAX(Case when Type=1 then id end)
    ,ReferenceNo
FROM
(
SELECT 
    EmployeeId=Per.[EmployeeId]
    ,EmployeeName=CONCAT(GI.LastName, ' ', GI.NameExtension,', ', GI.FirstName,' ', GI.MiddleName)
    ,Section=S.GroupDescription
    ,Position=Pos.PositionName
    ,id=AC.Id
    ,ReferenceNo=AC.ReferenceNo
    ,Type=AC.type
    ,LastName= GI.LastName
FROM [FGCIJOROSystemDB].[dbo].[Personnels] AS Per
LEFT JOIN Sections As S ON S.Id = Per.SectionId
LEFT JOIN FGCIHRDMasterlistSystemDB.dbo.EmployeesInformations AS EI ON EI.Id = Per.EmployeeId
LEFT JOIN FGCIHRDMasterlistSystemDB.dbo.GeneralInformations AS GI ON GI.Id = EI.GeneralInformationsId
LEFT JOIN FGCIHRDMasterlistSystemDB.dbo.Positions As Pos ON Pos.Id = EI.PositionsId
LEFT JOIN ActualAdvanceDetails AS AC ON AC.EmployeeId = Per.EmployeeId
WHERE S.IsChecklistGroup = 1
)
T
GROUP BY EmployeeId,EmployeeName,Section, Position,ReferenceNo
ORDER BY Section, LastName
```

Answer (score 0):

I refactor query! so this is the final answer! 
   `SELECT 
    EmployeeId
    ,EmployeeName
    ,Section
    ,Position
    ,MAX(Case when Type=0 then id end)
    ,MAX(Case when Type=0 then ReferenceNo end)
    ,MAX(Case when Type=1 then id end)
    ,MAX(Case when Type=1 then ReferenceNo end)
FROM
(
SELECT 
    EmployeeId=Per.[EmployeeId]
    ,EmployeeName=CONCAT(GI.LastName, ' ', GI.NameExtension,', ', GI.FirstName,' ', GI.MiddleName)
    ,Section=S.GroupDescription
    ,Position=Pos.PositionName
    ,id=AC.Id
    ,ReferenceNo=AC.ReferenceNo
    ,Type=AC.type
    ,LastName = GI.LastName
FROM [FGCIJOROSystemDB].[dbo].[Personnels] AS Per
LEFT JOIN Sections As S ON S.Id = Per.SectionId
LEFT JOIN FGCIHRDMasterlistSystemDB.dbo.EmployeesInformations AS EI ON EI.Id = Per.EmployeeId
LEFT JOIN FGCIHRDMasterlistSystemDB.dbo.GeneralInformations AS GI ON GI.Id = EI.GeneralInformationsId
LEFT JOIN FGCIHRDMasterlistSystemDB.dbo.Positions As Pos ON Pos.Id = EI.PositionsId
LEFT JOIN ActualAdvanceDetails AS AC ON AC.EmployeeId = Per.EmployeeId
WHERE S.IsChecklistGroup = 1
)
T
GROUP BY EmployeeId,EmployeeName,Section, Position,ReferenceNo
ORDER BY Section, EmployeeName`